# Leading 0 on operand leads to differing results in division when using Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

If you divide `11/10` in javascript you get `1.1`. If you divide `011/10` in javascript you get `0.9`. What causes the difference in results?

Comment: can you explain this behavior rather than just linking to bug. Like what's happening. Why adding zero is messing up the values..

Comment: then the result is because of octal constant has not much to do with floating point...

Comment: Adding a preceding `0` denotes an octal number. Just like adding a `0x` denotes a hex number. In other language such as Java you can even add `0b`, indicating a binary number. This is a common feature in most languages. Therefore, `011/10 = 0.9` is completely correct.

Comment: Maybe a question about octal constants does justify downvoting, but I'm guessing that the downvotes and close votes are based on an incorrect assumption that this is the old floating-point accuracy problem. That's not the case, and given that neither of the first two comments (now deleted) were able to correctly identify the problem, I'd say that this is actually a useful question. However, I'd change the title so it's clearer what it's about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`011` is an octal constant equal to 9.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Integers:

> Integers can be expressed in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), **and octal (base 8)**.
>
> **Leading 0 (zero) on an integer literal indicates it is in octal**. Octal integers can include only the digits 0-7.

Also note:

> Octal integer literals are *deprecated* and have been removed from the ECMA-262, Edition 3 standard (in strict mode).

C++ also has octal constants.

Answer (score 1):

If the number you are dealing with is represented as a string, you can specify the radix you want when casting it to a number by using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
+'011' // 9
parseInt('011') // 9
parseInt('011', 10) // 11
```